# IPhone Example : Login Page and then Navigate to another Screen (UI Table View)

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am an .Net Expert but a new to the IPhone App Development. Recently I have started workinf on Objective - c.

I need a help I need a example which shows a Login Screen and then Navigates to the another Screen (UITableView) when username and password and found correct.

As of now I am assuming that username and passwords are hardcoded in app.

I have tried to Design the Screen for Login UI but unable to Load the another ViewController but it wont worked

Can some one help me out with examples, Links?

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide on a navigation paradigm for your app first. Normally in this case, you'd just use a UINavigationController and use the pushViewController method to push a new view into your app.

The UINavigationController acts as a stack of views onto which you can either push new views (in your case) or pop views. Other options you have are listed nicely here - http://flyosity.com/application-design/iphone-application-design-patterns.php

This could be of some help for the tableviewcontroller + UINavigationController - http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-transitioning-between-views/